# Python: Writing the encrypted output of a Casear cipher and a columnar transposition cipher to a .txt file

Tags: python, powershell, encryption

I am hoping this is very simple to fix. The error I get within Windows Powershell using Python is as follows:

**Traceback (most recent call last): File "[filename.py]", line 66, in 
main(ciphertext) NameError: name 'ciphertext' is not defined**

My code:

```
def main():
# cipherOne contains encrypted Cesear cipher
 myMessage = cipherOne
 ciphertext = encryptMessage(key, myMessage)

 # Print the encrypted string in ciphertext to the screen, with
 # a | (called "pipe" character) after it in case there are spaces at
 # the end of the encrypted message.
 print(ciphertext)

def encryptMessage(key, message):
 # Each string in ciphertext represents a column in the grid.
 ciphertext = [''] * key

 # Loop through each column in ciphertext.
 for col in range(key):
     pointer = col

     # Keep looping until pointer goes past the length of the message.
     while pointer < len(message):
         # Place the character at pointer in message at the end of the
         # current column in the ciphertext list.
         ciphertext[col] += message[pointer]

         # move pointer over
         pointer += key

 # Convert the ciphertext list into a single string value and return it.
 return ''.join(ciphertext)

 # call main() function.

 if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

 target = open (filenamenew, 'a')

 target.write(ciphertext) #the error

 target.close()
```

I can print the encrypted string in ciphertext to the screen with no problems, but cannot work out how to get past this error, in which I can append the ciphertext to a .txt file.

Comment: `ciphertext` is a local variable in the scope of your functions. So `target.write(ciphertext)` is looking for a global variable and there isn't one. Have your `main` routine return the ciphertext, so that you can access it in your global scope.

Comment: I tried this but I now get the error: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None.

Comment: is the assignment for `ciphertext` failing because `key` is undefined?  (in main())

Comment: The same key is used for both the Caesar cipher and the columnar transposition. Sorry I perhaps should have referred to where my key is declared. The following code `key = (len(plaintext))` shows my key declaration. I did a test by using a different global variable: `target.write(cipherOne)` and it would print out (on screen) the correct ciphertext of the combination of the two ciphers, however would still not solve exporting this ciphertext to the [filenamenew.txt] file.

Answer (score 1):

RobertB is correct. Here's the exact code fix:

Just change the line "main()" to "ciphertext = main()" and your code should work. Your function already returns the text; you're just throwing it away right now by not assigning any variable to grab the return value.

Comment: I tried this but I now get the error: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Comment: @Frosty328 that's because you didn't follow RobertB's advice.  You have to add a return statement to your main function that returns the ciphertext.

Answer (score 0):

Following RobertB's advice, returning the **ciphertext** to the **main** routine solved the issue.